# How to get company logo as contact icon in Gmail and Inbox?

Tags: google, email, gmail, business

When I receive emails from big companies, when viewed in Gmail or Inbox the contact icon is actually their company logo. I am building a hotel website, and would like their emails to have their company logo as the contact picture in Gmail or Inbox, but the emails are not being sent FROM @gmail but from info@thehotelname.com. Is it possible to somehow tell Google to set the contact icon to the hotels logo for emails from @thehotelname.com?

Comment: Are these companies using the Google mail service but just under their domain (while the mail server still being Google)?

Comment: no, the mail is provided by the server hosting and their client.

Comment: I mean the companies you are referring to that currently have an image showing up. Im pretty sure this is just a google mail thing so if a company was using the google mail apps to run their company emails you would be able to set it within the google app settings. As far as i am aware there is no email headers or included data that is used to include an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should become a customer of [google apps for work](https://apps.google.com/intx/en/). you get what you asked about through binding of your domain and dns (mx record) to google. you will have many possibilities to customize the look and feel of all apps to become inline with your CI.

Comment: There must be some other way of doing this because I've seen it on emails sent through other (non-google) email providers...

Comment: @Evgeniy i am a google for work customer but mine does not appear like that. Any idea where i set it